# PHP from database and query

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a table:

> id, affiliate

Each time somebody clicks a link, a new row is inserted,

ID being the ID of the page, and affiliate being the ID of the affiliate.

For example:

> Page ID: 9 Affiliate ID: 1
>
> Page ID: 9 Affiliate ID: 2
>
> Page ID: 9 Affiliate ID: 3

I only have 3 affiliates.

I want to select this information, and group them by affiliate, for the ID.

I have tried this query:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`
>   WHERE `id` = '9' GROUP BY
>   `affiliate`

It works fine when I do it in php my admin, how do I get the info in PHP?

I have tried:

> $q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `table` WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "'
>   GROUP BY `affiliate`");
>
> $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

When trying to print the data onto the page, I am only getting one result.

Do I need to use a foreach/while loop to get all 3? How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: You ask her for a foreach/while solution but don't want a loop according to your comments? I'm confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do mysql_fetch_array() (or [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)) in a loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["affiliate"];
}
```

**UPDATE** (in accordance with comment):

If you ALWAYS have 3 rows in your result, probably [mysql_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) function would be helpful:

```
$firstAffiliate = mysql_result($q, 0, "affiliate");
$secondAffiliate = mysql_result($q, 1, "affiliate");
$thirdAffiliate = mysql_result($q, 2, "affiliate");
```

BTW, be careful and check, whether query actually returns 3 results.

Comment: I don't want to loop inside my content though, I want to basically define 3 variables which I can call further down the page, without having to place my content into a while loop.

Comment: Updated answer for case, when you have 3 rows only

Comment: @Kyle: A loop IS needed as the query returns 3 rows. Arguing against it is foolish AND bad practice to use mysql_result().

Answer (score 2):

Loop like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to loop inside my content though, I want to basically define 3 variables which I can call further down the page, without having to place my content into a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get list of `Affiliate ID`, you can consider this query

```
select group_concat(affiliate)
from table 
where id=9;
```

The above will return a comma separate value like `1,2,3` in single row

So, you can then in PHP explode using `,`, and the size of the exploded array is the same as `count(*)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variable to hold state inside the actual mysql statement itself. Try the following:

affiliates:
  page_id
  afil_id

set @page_id=0; 
select page_id, if(@page_id <> page_id, count(*), 0), @page_id:=page_id from clicks group by page_id;

Hope that helps